# Using Type Traits from Base Class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, type-traits

I am trying to understand the concept of type traits.

Say i have some templatized Class Hierachy like this and a client function:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
//...
    virtual bool inline isSymmetric() const = 0;
};    

template<typename T>
class ChildrenOperation : public Base<T>
{
public:
//...
    virtual bool inline isSymmetric() const override
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void clientFunction(const Base<T>& operation)
{
  //...
  if(operation.isSymmetric())
  {
      // use operation in one way 
  } else {
      // use operation in another way
  }
}
```

Obviously, clientFunction is polymorphic and different children can have different implementations of isSymmetric. 
However, since isSymmetric seems to be constant and really more of a type information, i've read about type traits and i was wondering whether it is possible to rewrite the client function to not depend on isSymmetric on runtime, but rather compile time.

I've tried adding a trait like this. But i am not sure how to specialize it and use it in a polymorphic context.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_symmetric {
  static const bool value = false;
};
```

Comment: Why not overload clientFunction?

Comment: You can't really use type traits in a polymorphic context because they operate on the *static* type of something, whereas virtual functions operate on the *dynamic* type.

Comment: This code won't work as it is written here. `Base` is a template yet you provide no template argument when you take it as a parameter in `clientFunction`. I guess you don't really want `Base` to be a template, only the child, but I'm not really sure what you intend to do with this code.

Comment: @petersohn you are right. sorry, forgot to mention that client function also is a template of T, the template type is just forwarded here

Comment: @Axalo I am not sure how to accomplish this

Comment: @TartanLlama I think you are right. So I can only benefit from type trait features, when i certainly know the explicit static type?

Comment: Does `isSymmetric` depend of `T` or of `ChildrenOperation<T>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 ChildrenOperation<T>

Comment: CRTP lets you move dynamic dispatch to static dispatch.  But it probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If being symmetric depends on the concrete type derived from `Base`, then you cannot use a type traits for this situation. Type traits are evaluated in compile time, so if you have a polymorphic type which's traits are not known at compile time, then you cannot use type traits.

One possible solution, if the symmetricity is really constant, is this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(bool symmetric) : symmetric(symmetric) {}

    bool isSymmetric() {
        return symmetric;
    }

    // ...

private:
    bool symmetric;
};

class ChildrenOperation : public Base {
public:
    ChildrenOperation() : Base(true) {}

    // ...
};
```

I did not use the templates here because they are irrelevant in this case. Of course, if symmetricity depends on T then you can use type traits, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_symmetric : public std::false_type {};

template <>
struct is_symmetric<SymmetricT> : public std::true_type {};
```

So the solution depends on whether the trait depends only on the dynamic type of the object, in which case you should use the fist code, the template parameter, in which case you should use the second code, or both. From your example, it's not entirely clear which is your situation.